# Check captcha does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Help please deal with CAPTCHA. At me all is normal it is drawn, through Ajax the entered code is sent to file insert.php where at me the form handler. But the check does not work there. What do not enter in the input field, everything is considered correct

My form and ajax

```
<form action="/data/insert.php" method="POST" id="guest-form" name="reg">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <textarea id="message" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <img src="data/captcha.php" alt="Картинка" /><br />
    <input id ="captcha" type="text" name="captcha" /><br />

    <input id="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();
                var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
                if(username || email || message || captcha  === ''){
                    alert('Please input data in all fields');
                }
                else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,        
                    url: '/data/insert.php',
                    data: {username: username, email: email, message: message, captcha: captcha},
                    success: function(data) {
                    }
                });
            }
            });
        });
```

The php handler

```
 require_once 'db.php';
require_once 'captcha.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["captcha"]) && $_SESSION["captcha"]===$_POST["captcha"]){ echo "Текст введен верно"; }
else { 
    echo "Текст введен не верно";
}
unset($_SESSION["captcha"]);

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "alekspvn"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = "123"; // Пароль БД
    $db_table = "book"; // Имя Таблицы БД

$connect_db=mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS)   
    or die("No connection with SQL"); 

    mysql_select_db("guests_db",$connect_db);

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connect_db);

    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (username,email,message) VALUES ('$username','$email','$message')");

    if ($result = 'true'){
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }else{
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Because you __do nothing__ to prevent inserting when captcha is incorrect.

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: If captcha entered correctly - do stuff, else - not do stuff.

Comment: Where to do the test? in handler after start session?

Comment: Where else can you do it?

Comment: yes, if,else. In what file i must do that?

Comment: In your php handler, I think.

Comment: Is this not a test? session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["captcha"]) && $_SESSION["captcha"]===$_POST["captcha"]){ echo "Текст введен верно"; }
else { 
    echo "Текст введен не верно";
}

Comment: It is a test but it allows to do anything after it is completed.